# Sessions in PHP, login script

Tags: php, html, authentication, web

doing a simple login for my website, which will hopefully keep the user logged in over a period of time, the scripts looks like this:

```
<?php 


/* $con make a connection with database */
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 

//select  database
mysql_select_db("blogass"); 

/* Below two commands will store the data in variables came from form input */
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


/* below two commands are sql injection which stops extra characters as input */
$user=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where
username='$username' AND 
password='$password' "); 

$count=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count==1) 
/* $count checks if username and password are in same row */
{ 
 echo "Login Successful";
 $hour = time() + 3600;  

}
else
{ 
echo "Username or password is incorrect";
}
?>
```

Im having trouble putting a session in, i know its simple, but i cant put my finger on it! i want it to display whos logged in on my index.php page and if nobody is logged in, to display a message asking a user to login/register. Basically i want a user to stay logged on throughout the time they are on the site. Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You should familiarize with [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Username and Password authentication:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$username' AND password='$password' "); 

$count=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count==1) 
/* $count checks if username and password are in same row */
{ 
echo "Login Successful";
$hour = time() + 3600;  
                       <--- PUT HERE INSTRUCTION BELOW
}
```

You should store username in a $_SESSION variable when you verify that he is authenticated:

```
 $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
```

At beginning of all other pages you should put command

```
session_start();
```

and then use an if statment to check if gloabal session variable user is set:

```
<?php

if( isset($_SESSION['user'])){

?>

//HTML of page if user is authenticated

<?php

}else{

?>

//HTML of page if user is authenticated

<?php


}

?>
```

Comment: @Volvic I edited my answer in order to fit your question, check if its ok!

Comment: I have added the session in, i have checked that it worked as it will display "welcome (username)" on the page after i click the login button. When i press back and go onto my home page i have tried to retrieve the username, i am having trouble retrieving the session variable on other pages! Having a nightmare with this, feel so stupid haha!

Comment: Volvic:) You need to redirect to your *home page* after successful log in. Make use of `header("your home page URL")` or Javascript to redirect to your *home page*. What way did you try to retrieve the user name stored into the session?

Comment: using this after a successful login "header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;".. erm, this is my code on my index page: session_start();
echo "You are logged in as ", $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

Comment: What's that? You need to assign the session value to a new variable like this. `$username=$_SESSION['username'];` then echo it like this `echo $username;`. It looks like that you're trying assign the value of '$username' to your session as you already did on your log in page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `session_start()` at the top of your script.

Then, upon successful login, set, say, `$_SESSION['user'] = array('login'=>'john', 'level'=>1);`.

Then, just check against the session array and alter your textual output accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First, at the top of the file call `session_start()`, then put any variables you want in the session in the `$_SESSION` super-global.

For example, if you wanted to store the username,

```
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Then on a different page, call `session_start()` again, and you can access `$_SESSION['username']`!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `session_start();` any time you need to access or store information in a session variable.  You can then assign session variables to the `$_SESSION[]` superglobal.

You can then assign variables like:

`$_SESSION['variable_name'] = "You can use strings, numbers, booleans, etc here.";`

Check out the [PHP Manual on Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to modify your code as follows.

```
<?php 
/* $con make a connection with database */
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 

session_start();  //Add this.
//select  database
mysql_select_db("blogass"); 

/* Below two commands will store the data in variables came from form input */
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];


/* below two commands are sql injection which stops extra characters as input */
$user=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where
username='$username' AND 
password='$password' "); 

$count=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count==1) 
/* $count checks if username and password are in same row */
{ 
     echo "Login Successful";
     $hour = time() + 3600;  
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  //Add this.

}
else
{ 
    echo "Username or password is incorrect";
}
?>
```

In PHP, you need to start session **first** using the `session_start()` function before you use, destroy or unset the session in your PHP script.

Comment: Should probably not set the `$_SESSION['username']` until after the username password pair has been checked though. Otherwise he may get a bug where you're logged in whether you get the password correct or not.

Comment: @user1:) Correct-Modified accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could save all the session stuff in an array, as in the code above, then check for the presence of an array.

When you set the array:

```
 $_SESSION['user'] = array(
  'isAuth' => true,
  'login'  => 'john',
  'lname'  => 'Smith', etc etc

);
```

Then, check on each page for this session var:

```
session_start(); //before headers are called
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user']['isAuth'] !== true){
  //redirect them to a login page
  header('Location: /login_page.php');
}

//auth content here...
```